# When and where should I use a "fetchingData" state for normalized data in Redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

If I have `teachers` and `students` in a Redux store as separate, normalized states describing arrays of entities, where should I put a property that describes when I'm actively fetching that data?

Answer (score 1):

Use new state like "LoadingState" or something similar for this state. Inside that,
it's something like

```
const initialLoadingState = {
    isFetchingStudents: false,
    isFetchingTeachers: false,
    ...
}
```

Comment: I like this idea. So something like: teachers students loadingState->isFetchingStudents, isFetchingTeachers? Sorry can't draw it out. Could you maybe diagram it?

Comment: @valkn0t It's just simple object.

Comment: What happens when your store grows, and the amount of resources I have grows? And containers begin to have access to isFetching* of entities they don't care about?

Comment: @valkn0t It's centralized store, any container can access to the store if necessary, so in teacher component, you may only need to care about LoadingState.isFetchingTeachers, even though you can also access students' state through LoadingState,isFetchingStudents. It doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: Just because the store is centralized doesn't mean you should expose the entire state to a component, especially when you don't have to. Hence why you only map certain parts of state to container props in mapStateToProps; unless you literally just return the entire state in that function.

Comment: @valkn0t Yeah you already know the practice. So inside your teacher component, you can mapStateToProps like{ isFetching: state.LoadingState.isFetchingTeachers }

Comment: Would any asynchronous state manipulation be grouped by type similarly? Ex. LoadingState, AddingState, ChangingState, FooBarringState? With associated isLoadingTeachers, isAddingTeachers, isChangingTeachers, isFooBarringTeachers?

Answer (score 1):

One more way could be is to group related flags into same object:

```
teachers: {
  entries: []    // Student[]
  loading: false // boolean
}
```

Comment: But I wouldn't be accessing data in a normalized fashion; instead of accessing the first teacher with teachers[0], it would be teachers.entries[0]? And this is also coupling data access with storage

Comment: @valkn0t you decide what design you prefer. with what I suggest it's very clear and convenient for both components (`mapStateToProps ({ teachers }) => ({ teachers })`, `const { teachers: { entries, loading } } = this.props`) and for reducers where you can easily control loading flag in the same reducer instead of setting data and loading flag in different store reducers.